QTextDocumentWriter и символ возврат каретки '\r'
Пытаюсь сохранить содержимое QTextEdit в текстовый файл с помощью QTextDocumentWriter в ОС Windows и обнаружил, что в сохранённом файле для переноса строки используется только символ '\n' вместо комбинации '\r\n'. Соответственно стандартный блокнот некорректно отображает файл. Как можно QTextDocumentWriter заставить сохранять файл с учётом этой особенности?
QTextEdit *memo;
//...
QTextDocumentWriter writer;
writer.setFormat("plaintext");
writer.setFileName("lol.txt");
writer.write(memo->document());


Как вариант используя replace
writer.write(memo.toPlainText().replace(QRegularExpression("\\n"), "\r\n"))

но вообще - вопрос спорный как и ответ. Все зависит от дальнейших целей.

Лучше уж регулярку \\r?\\n.

Почему вопрос спорный? QTextDocumentWriter лучше не использовать?

@Kebuda, да просто как и в какой формат Вы дальше будете писать - это не известно. Я например пишу в ODF. Так там все равно на эти потуги. Что касаемо регулярки - я не очень спец в них. Может предыдущий комментатор и прав. Да и подходит мой совет если только для обычного Plain текста.  Просто посмотри в этом направлении.
